# C Windows/Linux Buffer Overflow Exploits

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have looked at how the buffer overflows work and have to determine that the program (with gcc) must compile with the following parameters: -fno-stackprotector and -z execstack.
You have to tell the kernel that it does not randomly allocate the addresses every time you start the program (which, however, is not absolutely necessary, just makes the buffer overflow easier)

Should a person now write an exploit e. g. against Apache, the Apache Developers will not compile the program with the above parameters.

How would these exploits still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fno-stack-protector` disables canary which is a random value placed between a function frame and saved instruction pointer. `-zexecstack` makes the stack memory region executable so that code execution is easy. With both these protections disabled its much easier to write exploits. Sometimes Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is also disabled which means that all offsets in memory will be same on each execution.
For people who are starting with exploit development these protections are turned off so that they appreciate the techniques and attack vectors.

However with actual softwares such as apache, they are usually compiled with all protections (additionally PIE, RELRO). But there exist techniques that will help you to get code execution. One of them is called Return Oriented Programming(ROP) when used properly helps you defeat NX(non executale memory regions). Additionally to bypass ASLR/PIE you'll need one more `leak` primitive to get addresses from the memory. Its not impossible to write exploits for modern software its just difficult.